# Can a dll run as stand alone application in dot net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, exe

1. Can dll run as stand alone application?
2. If yes how, please give example?

I have a dll now I want use it as a .exe so it is possible how can I do it?

Comment: Develop it directly as an executeable?!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run dll at all. You can create exe and add your dll as a reference.

Comment: that is I know? my question is Can a dll run as stand alone application without use as a references?\